# SQL Efficiency More tables or more rows

Tags: mysql

Say I have photo managing database that currently have 100 users registered to it each having 10000 photos to bounded to their user_id. Each user will only have access to their own photos.

Is it more efficient to have 100 tables (with the user_id as the table name) for each user with their respective 10,000 photos **OR** A single table consisting of all 1,000,000 photos **OR** there are simply no differences in any way related to the performance of the database?

In both cases, the number will continue to increase (i.e. More users or more photos)

**EDIT:** I am currently using MySQL to build the database and was initially considering on storing the links to the images which will most likely be stored in a single folder. I think I have gotten a better idea on what how to approach this! Thanks for the responses!

Comment: Is this for MySQL or SQL Server?  Are you storing images/binary data in the database, or just user information?  Either way, you almost certainly don't want a unique table for each user.

Comment: As a general rule, your schema should be static (absent changes to your application code that require a schema change).  So a single table with 1m photos is the best way—properly indexed, it'll perform better than separate tables too.

Comment: If you are planning to store the actual image binaries in a table - don't do it. If you are planning to store the photos' references in the database... For basic image information it is possibily sufficient to save the images in a directory with the user's ID on disk - this way you could use the file name to store some information and it will be more efficient. When it comes to do more advanced operations with the images and the meta data then of course it will be better to store the references in a single table. Keep the amount of fields in a table of this size to a minimum though.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want just two tables for the many to one relationship.  A table with user IDs (ad probably other user information), a table with photos and user IDs (foreign keyed to the users table).

Something like this:
user table

```
UserID  Name  DateJoined  etc.
1       Dan   2015-01-01  ...
2       Jim   2015-02-01  ...
```

photo table (you could store the actual photo in the table, if you're going to do that use FILESTREAM on SQL Server; I don't think I'd recommend it on MySQL)

```
PhotoID  UserID PhotoPath        PhotoTitle
1        1      '/img/asdf.jpg'  'My favorite'
2        2      '/img/asdf2.jpg' 'First!'
3        1      '/img/asdf3.gif' 'Animated favorite'
```

Your ImagePath will either have to be uniquely generated (use a GUID/UUID for file name, store all user's photos in a particular directory, or something along those lines).

If you really just want to store photos and associate them with the user, you may want to consider a NoSQL/Document database.

Comment: Why would the OP need the third (association) table in this case?  Photos are all owned by a *single* user, so an `owner` column in the second table should suffice to create a 1:many relationship.  Association tables are only needed for many:many relationships.

Comment: Ahh, I missed the part where each user owns their own photos.  You're right.  I'll amend the post.

Comment: If the only dynamic information you want to store is the title I don't see why you would want to go through the overhead of having a huge table like this. Saving the data in the file system (using the user id as the directory name and the encoded title as the file name) would do the job. See my comment at the question.

Comment: Because you could (and will) want to store other metadata in that table.  Last access of the photo, who likes the photo, etc.  You'll also have an easier time getting multiple servers to access the information and metadata in SQL than on a fileshare.  I'd take a NoSQL over that, but even then you'll eventually want relational data (who likes and so forth)

Comment: If you would want to add more metadata then why not save ONLY the metadata in the table and NOT the file reference? 1 million rows or more in a mysql table gets very slow very quickly - you would want to minimise the amount of fields to the absolute minimum to keep the row size small.

Comment: You'd still need some identifier to link the photo binary data to the metadata...  And I'm not as familar with MySQL as SQL Server, but there should be ways for MySQL to properly handle >1m rows performantly...

Comment: +1 about the suggestion of NoSQL. I would make the images self-referencing based on the row id, the title or something like that. Unfortunately when dealing with large tables MySQL is not quite as good as MSSQL. 1million is probably still alright, but let's assume the table grows beyond that as well and you want to run reports on it too plus it being a picture management app there are going to be a lot of queries on this table as well. So for anything > 1m I'd be starting to look at table partitioning - if this is needed at 2m, 5m or 20m depends on row size, your app architecture and usage.

Comment: @phpPhil, "very slow, very quickly"? I have to disagree. Assuming the file/name path and name are each 100 characters, the clustered index would only be 208MB (any decent MySQL server is going to have this all in memory), and a secondary index for user lookup is only going to be 8MB (a little bigger with InnoDB's 15/16 preference), but you get my point.

Comment: I see your point, yes, and I'm not saying I disagree. But it's not really about the size. It's about blocking queries, concurrency, etc. - why storing data you don't need in a large table. All things that exponentially increase response time with the amount of rows. So keeping it lean, that's my point :)